# Keyboard events called before UITextView delegate events

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uitextview

I have a `UITableView` with `UITextViews` and `UITextFields` on it's cells. As obvious the keyboard overlaps the lower cells and you cannot see what you are typing.
So I want to scroll the `tableview` to get the field visible.
I wrote the code the `iOS` docs recommended: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

**BUT** the keyboard event callback `keyboardWillShow:` is called **before** the `UITextView` edit callback `textViewDidBeginEditing:`. So I cannot set the active textview when I try to calculate the scrolling I need to make the active textview visible.

Anyone knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the code out of `keyboardWillShow:` and add it into `keyboardDidShow:` This is obviously called after it has been presented ...

If you're using notifications you need to add:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `textViewDidBeginEditing(_)` is called **after** `keyboardDidShow(_)`